# AudioKit AKSequencer and Ableton Link

Tags: audiokit

Is it possible to use AKSequencer with Ableton Link accurately ?

I couldn't find any info / way to determine output time etc of AKSequencer that would seem to be needed to implement Ableton Link correctly.

Would I need to create my own sequencer driven by an audio unit callback to get the best result ?